# impose a blur image

Tags: html, css

please help to solve the problem
 
there is a picture, it is necessary to impose the top part of it blurred green background. should appear as a result of [so](http://joxi.ru/52aJEBZfDVoDA0)
 
I tried to solve the problem, using photoshop filter "Gaussian Blur" to the green background of the source. just tried to apply css-property "filter". as a result of not solved the problem (there is aliasing green glass, but there is a blur). here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fr4wh935/2/)

css:

```
.sk_a1 .sk_meta1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: -10px;
    border-top: 7px solid #3c5f4f;
    background: #3c5f4f;
    opacity: 0.95;
    -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -ms-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also put the image again as background and set a small container in front. I think this is what you actually intended to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/fr4wh935/9/

```
.sk_meta1 {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
   filter: blur(2px);
   background-image: url(http://static5.smi2.net/img/300x300/2257778.jpeg);
   background-position:  bottom left;
 ...
```

and at its pseudo element `:before`

```
.sk_meta1:before {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
    content : ''; 
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach it also works and good one in my opinion, but maybe the blur effect at the edge of the container is not so clear.

Comment: Thanks mate. I made the edge sharp now.

Comment: Now it also works for firefox. I only missed the `-moz-filter`. Updated example and code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Css [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) and CSS [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) (look at my code in class `.blur`).

The "trick" is to create a new image (part that will be blurred and masked) that will be positioned on top of the original image.

Here you a quick example (only HTML and CSS).

http://jsfiddle.net/fr4wh935/6/

Please notice that CSS blur and clip-path may not be supported by all browsers and that you need to add new image tag to your code.

Alternatively you can consider creating the blur effect with a Photoshop, replacing your image file with the effect desired, this will work obviously on any browsers.

In order to support old version of Firefox you should

To this point the blur effect will work in Chrome, Safari (mobile and desktop) and Firefox 35+. To gain support for earlier versions of Firefox, we need to apply an SVG filter:

Create a file and save it as blur.svg, uses this code:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <filter id="blur"> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3" /> </filter> </svg>
```

CSS will need to change in order to point that svg file:

```
.blur {  filter: url(blur.svg#blur); -webkit-filter: blur(5px); filter: blur(5px); }
```

---

```
.blur{
      filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    position: absolute;
  clip: rect(200px, 300px, 300px, 0px);
}   

.sk_wrap{
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 960px;
        }

            .sk_item{
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                overflow: hidden;
                float: left;
                margin: 10px;
            }

                .sk_a1{
                    display: block;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 300px;
                }

                    .sk_a1 img{
                        display: block;
                        width: 100%;
                        min-height: 100%;

                    }

                    .sk_a1 .sk_meta1_outer{
                        width: 105%;
                        height: 105px;
                        position: absolute;
                        bottom: -2px;
                        left: -2px;
                        right: -2px;
                        overflow: hidden;
                    }

                        .sk_a1 .sk_meta1{
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100px;
                            position: absolute;
                            bottom: 0;
                            left: 0;
                            right: -10px;
                            background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) left top repeat;



                            border-top: 7px solid #3c5f4f;
                            /*background: #3c5f4f;
*/                          opacity: 0.95;
                            -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
                            -moz-filter: blur(2px);
                            -ms-filter: blur(2px);
                            -o-filter: blur(2px);
                            filter: blur(2px);
                            /*margin: 0 -5px -5px;*/
                        }   

                    .sk_a1 .sk_meta2{
                        width: 260px;
                        height: 60px;
                        position: absolute;
                        bottom: 5px;
                        left: 0;
                        right: 0;
                        padding: 15px 20px 20px;
                        overflow: hidden;

                        font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                        color: #fff;
                        text-align: center;
                    }   

                        .sk_a1 .sk_title1{
                            font-size: 25px;

                            overflow: hidden;
                            margin-bottom: 5px;
                            display: block;
                        }   

                        .sk_a1 .sk_announce{
                            font-size: 15px;
                            overflow: hidden;

                            display: block;
                        }  

<div class="sk_wrap">
    <div class="sk_item">
        <a class="sk_a1" href="http://" id="674190">
            <img  class="blur" alt=
        "Роботы Роботы Роботы Роботы Роботы Роботы" src=
        "http://static5.smi2.net/img/300x300/2257778.jpeg">
            <img class="" alt=
        "Роботы Роботы Роботы Роботы Роботы Роботы" src=
        "http://static5.smi2.net/img/300x300/2257778.jpeg">

        <div class="sk_meta1_outer">
            <div class="sk_meta1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="sk_meta2">
            <div class="sk_title1">
                Роботы Роботы Р
            </div>

            <div class="sk_announce">
                Роботы Роботы Роботы Роботы
            </div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your answer as well. Good way of solving the stated problem!

Comment: I have edit my answer in order to support old version of Firefox. Please let me know if it helps. Thanks